# Change backgroundcolor of PushButton (hyperref package)

Tags: pdftex, hyperref

I would like to create a pushbutton and change its background color. Is this feasible ? And how ?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

\PushButton[
  name=additem,
  borderwidth=0.5pt,
  bordercolor=blue,
  backgroundcolor=red % why doesn't this work ?
]{\textcolor{blue}{Add an item}}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: Add an item PushButton]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hyperref doesn't contain code to set the background color here. It is theoretically possible to add it, but it has the side effect to overwrite the text on the button. I would suggest to use a colorbox instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}

{ % not so good ...
 \makeatletter 
 \patchcmd\PDFForm@Push{/BC[\Fld@bordercolor]}{/BC[\Fld@bordercolor]/BG[\Fld@bcolor]}{}{\fail}
 \PushButton[
  name=additem,
  borderwidth=0.5pt,
  bordercolor=blue,
  backgroundcolor=red,
]{\textcolor{blue}{\strut Add an item}}
}

\bigskip

\fboxsep=0pt
\colorbox{red}{%
 \PushButton[
  name=additem,
  borderwidth=0.5pt,
  bordercolor=blue,
]{\textcolor{blue}{\strut Add an item}}}

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]